# Query to bring through today's values only

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a query where:

```
WHERE a.jobdate >=GETDATE()-1
```

This brings though data from today and yesterday; I understand this is because GETDATE = now.

However, all I want is to see is data from today only.

Is there any way the above query can be amended - probably not using GETDATE - so I can achieve this?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Why you don't want to use `GETDATE()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you use `GETDATE()`.  If the format is a datetime format you can `cast(YOURDATETIME as date)` to achieve the result of pulling just the current day.  so... either

```
a.jobdate = getdate()
```

OR

```
cast(a.jobdate as date) = getdate()
```

Comment: WHERE CAST(a.jobDate AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) did the job; thanks for getting me on the right track.